# Translation for frontend

Tags: translation, front-end

In my plugin I have many strings to translate for the backend and only a few for the frontend. For the visitors of the website it is nicer to read the words in the language of the site. Is there a more elegant way to mark for the translators which words appear in the frontend or backend than [_x](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/):

_x("string to translate", "In Frontend", "text-domain")

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it *matter* to the translators if a string is used in the back or the front of a website? Translation is meant to improve the user experience throughout the website, which IMHO includes both the front and the back.

Comment: It is nice for the visitors, if everything is displayed in their language. It's not about the whole website, but only what my plugin generates.
The admin in the backend is mostly alone and may know english. 
For the frontend there is less to translate, in the backend much more. An official language pack is not generated until 90% is translated. 
Therefore I have the question, whether one can mark the translations for frontend and backend somehow, so that at least the frontend is translated. I as plugin developer would then download the translated at translate.wordpress.org and integrate.